# XCode 9.3 "The argument is invalid" when i installing an IPA on Apple TV

Tags: xcode, arguments, symlink

I updated **Xcode** to **9.3**. and after i get the error message `"App install failed - The argument is invalid"` when i am installing an `IPA` on my Apple TV. With the earlier Version everything was fine.

From reading the other questions i didn't get it fixed :( i read something about to delete the symlinks. Can anybody tell me what i exactly have to do to delete the symlinks? 
I know i have to search with this command `find ./ -type l -exec ls -l {} \;`
but where do i have to search and how can i delete the symlink results?

I am not always working with Xcode so i am not really in to it. I hope anybody can help :(

Answer (score 2):

Now after 2 days of trying i finally found the solution.

I have unpaired the connection between Xcode and my Apple TV and did a new Pairing between the devices. After that everything was fine. The error message was gone and i could install my API on my Apple TV.

I really hate xcode!!!

Comment: I saw this same error when trying to install an ipa onto my iPhone that was connected to Xcode via wifi....changed it to a cabled connection and it worked...thx for the idea!